# Place a single ring on the soil, Place a fir

Tags: english, symbols

Place a single piece of ring on the soil,
Place a first stick vertically on above of a single piece of ring,
Place a second stick vertically on below of a single piece of ring.
What symbol did you get?

Comment: Is "soil" important, or do you just mean "ground"?
Placing the second stick below (which is what I assume "on below of" means) something on the ground would require digging.

Comment: Also, it's not clear whether these are three different parts of a ring, or the same one in all three cases.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> The symbol for cents? ￠

because

> A 'single piece of ring' would give you the open 'c' and then the sticks vertically above and below give you the vertical strike-through

Comment: Wrong. That's not an actual question

Comment: What's not a question?

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Φ φ Phi
>  Although the line goes through it instead of just above and below.